# CSS 100% height scrolling

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone I have one problem about scrolling.

I created this full page **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/full/qEVeje/)** and edit page **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/qEVeje)** from codepen.io . In this demo you can see there is a left sidebar for message area.

I am using this CSS for `.message_area` but `overflow-y: scroll;` is not working:

```
.message_area {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    width:331px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    bottom:0;
    top:64px;
    left:0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

What is the problem here anyone can tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` from the `body`

Comment: Why did you put this ?

Comment: I tried something before. it has stayed that way :)